# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'dict' objects error with Bit.ly_API

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, directory

I'm having a bit a problem. I'm still very new to python. So dict's are very new to me. I know of solve problems as I go and hopefully learn from my mistakes.

So the error is below with 'shortURL' in the first text variable. Just wondering what the issue means and how I could go about solving it? I've had a look online and didn't fully understand why as a lot of issues where looking at string but the bit.ly_api just return a URL.

Thanks for any help :)

```
    print("")
    print("Welcome to Sole Retriever Tweet Formulator b0.1")
    type = (raw_input('What kind of tweet would you like to do?' + '\n' + '1. Store URL + Website Site' + '\n' + '2.Website URL Only' + '\n'))
    if type == ('1'):
        store1 = (raw_input('What is the store name hosting the Off-White x Converse Raffle? '))
        storeURL = (raw_input('What is the direct URL to the raffle? '))
        shortURL = b.shorten(storeURL)
        text = ('Woof! ' + store1 + ' raffle is now live for the Off-White x Converse Chuck Taylor!' + '\n' + '\n' + shortURL + '\n' + '\n' + 'For raffle details and where to enter check and filter by "live" -' + '\n' + '\n' + 'https://www.soleretriever.com/off-white-x-converse-chuck-taylor/' + '\n' + '\n' + '#soleretriever #offwhite #converse #sneakers')
        print (text)
        os.system("echo '%s' | pbcopy" % text)
        print ('\n')
        print ('Copied to Clipboard')
        twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
        twitter.update_status(status=text)
    if type == ('2'):   
        store = (raw_input('What is the store name hosting the Off-White x Converse Raffle? '))
        text = ('Woof! ' + store + ' raffle is now live for the Off-White x Converse Chuck Taylor!' + '\n' + '\n' + 'For raffle details and where to enter check and filter by "live" -' + '\n' + '\n' + 'https://www.soleretriever.com/off-white-x-converse-chuck-taylor/' + '\n' + '\n' + '#soleretriever #offwhite #converse #sneakers')
        print (text)
        os.system("echo '%s' | pbcopy" % text)
        print ('\n')
        print ('Copied to Clipboard')
        twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
        twitter.update_status(status=text)
```

Comment: What dos the stack trace from your error say? Does it give any hints what line it’s on and where you’re trying to join a string with a dict?

Comment: @Sean it was on line 31, but I've removed the top lines of code as it contains my API keys. 

The code it 's having trouble with it below. With the  + shortURL +

`text = ('Woof! ' + store1 + ' raffle is now live for the Off-White x Converse Chuck Taylor!' + '\n' + '\n' + shortURL + '\n' + '\n' + 'For raffle details and where to enter check and filter by "live" -' + '\n' + '\n' + 'https://www.soleretriever.com/off-white-x-converse-chuck-taylor/' + '\n' + '\n' + '#soleretriever #offwhite #converse #sneakers')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `b.shorten(storeURL)` will return a `dict` with key/value pairs, including the `url`. Python will throw that error when you concatenate a string and dict like you're doing in `print()`. I'd suggest something like:

```
response = b.shorten(storeURL)
shortURL = response['url']
```

Comment: Hello! thank you for your response. So when I try this I get an attribute error. 
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'url'

Comment: Without the import statements I'm guessing at which library you're using. I'd check the docs or use something like `print "response keys : %s" %  dict.keys()` to have a look.

Comment: Ahh I can attach those below - 

`#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
import os
import sys
import site
import threading
import time
import bitly_api
from twython import Twython
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta`

Comment: That might work with `response['url']`. It has been a while since I've worked with Python, sorry!

Comment: This worked, thank you so much !! So why did it have to be in [ ] ?

Comment: When you use the `.` it is looking for an attribute of the object. The `d[key]` syntax indicates you want to look up a key/value pair that will have different behaviour (e.g.: a KeyError if it's not found). Have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict.